# Does arr = [val] * N have liner or constant time?

Tags: python, algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to solve some problem at codility.
And I am wondering whether `answ = [max] * N` has linear or constant time ?

```
def solution(N, A):

    answ = [0] * N
    max = 0

    for item in A:
        if item > N:
            answ = [max] * N # this line here. Linear or constant time ?
        else:
            answ[item-1] += 1

            if answ[item-1] > max:
                max = answ[item-1]

    return answ
```

List A has length M.
So, if time is constant I will receive O(M) complexity of algorithm.
If linear, I will receive O(M*N) complexity.

Comment: The assignment `answ = [0] * N` will be linear in N.  How could it not be?  You're creating a list of length N.  Each element has to be set to 0.  There is no way the list could be created in constant time.

Comment: You can use `collections.defaultdict(lambda max=max: max)` instead to get a dict where the values default to `max`. It will work in average amortized O(1) per operation.

Comment: Except that list multiplication creates multiple references to *the same* object. I'm not sure what happens with integers, and of course you do need to create `N` references, but it's not *in principle* the same as creating `N` copies of whatever is in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. CPython lists are merely arrays of pointers. Check out struct definition in listobject.h:

https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/listobject.h#l22

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    /* Vector of pointers to list elements.  list[0] is ob_item[0], etc. */
    PyObject **ob_item;

    /* ob_item contains space for 'allocated' elements.  The number
     * currently in use is ob_size.
     * Invariants:
     *     0 <= ob_size <= allocated
     *     len(list) == ob_size
     *     ob_item == NULL implies ob_size == allocated == 0
     * list.sort() temporarily sets allocated to -1 to detect mutations.
     *
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the list is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
    Py_ssize_t allocated;
} PyListObject;
```

If that doesn't convince you....

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: def build_list(N):
   ...:     start = time.time()
   ...:     lst = [0]*N
   ...:     stop = time.time()
   ...:     return stop - start
   ...: 

In [4]: x = list(range(0,1000000, 10000))

In [5]: y = [build_list(n) for n in x]

In [6]: plt.scatter(x, y)
Out[6]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x7f2d0cae7438>

In [7]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're populating an array sized `N` with the value `max`, that means you're doing `N` writes - hence it is linear in complexity.

There are some data structures that can receive a "default" value for all items that aren't explicitly declared with a value, in a bound array size. However, Python's list() isn't such a structure.